# A Trigonometric Identity in Boltzmann transport theory

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to show to the identity below:
\begin{equation}
\cos\theta' = \sin\theta\sin\alpha\sin\phi+\cos\theta\cos\alpha
\end{equation}
The angles are given below:[image]
Anyone can shade some light about how to prove the identity?

Comment: Is $E$ in the $yz$-plane?

Comment: E is an unit vector not necessarily on yz-plane.

Comment: Is $\theta' = \alpha - \theta$?

Comment: Assuming unit vectors, we can write $k' = (\sin\alpha \cos\phi, \sin\alpha \sin\phi, \cos\alpha)$ and $E= (\sin\theta \cos\psi, \sin\theta \sin\psi, \cos\theta)$ (for some angle $\psi$ not shown, serving as $E$'s counterpart to $\phi$), and then calculate
$$\cos\theta' = k'\cdot E = \sin\alpha\cos\phi\sin\theta\cos\psi+\sin\alpha\sin\phi\sin\theta\sin\psi+\cos\alpha\cos\theta$$ This will match the given formula when (and only when) $\cos\psi=0$ and $\sin\psi=1$; that is, when $\psi=90^\circ$. (So $E$ *is* in the $yz$-plane.)

Comment: I have been looking at your new question: sorry, I haven't any clue. But browsing your other questions, I found that this one could be given an "enlightning" answer.

Comment: @Jean Marie. I am glad that you reached me. Thank you. The new question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155671/saddle-point-of-matrix-valued-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to give an answer to this old question by placing it in perspective (we are in 3D :)):

$$\cos c \ = \ \cos a \cos b+\sin a \sin b \color{red}{\cos C}$$

is a fundamental formula called the *"first spherical law of cosines"*, "first" because there is a second one, somewhat dual of this one, both of them associated to a reference spherical triangle, which is the trace or the given vectors on the unit sphere. The different forms under which one can find/apply these laws is summarized on figure 1, extracted from fig 3.12 of this interesting (astronomy oriented) [slideshow](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/dynamics_cheat_sheet/rech3.htm):

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

One finds explanations and proofs at different places like [this one]
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines).

The fact that you have a $\color{red}{\sin A}$ instead of a $\color{red}{\cos A}$ in formula (1) is because, instead of $A:=\phi$, one must consider the complementary angle $\frac{\pi}{2} - A$.

I could detail all that, but I think it is rather easy to understand.