# Saddle point of matrix valued field

Tags: calculus

I am trying to work out the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9810282). The authors find the saddle point of the action given below [equation (34) of the paper]
$$Z = \int DX DY DQ~e^{\frac{-1}{2u}\int d^{d}x Tr{Q^{2}}}~e^{iS_{X}[x]}e^{iS_{Y}[y]}e^{\int d^{d}x Tr~ln[-i\Omega-i(\frac{\nabla^{2}}{2m}+\epsilon_{F})\mathbf{1}]+\eta\Lambda+Q(x)-\sqrt{2\pi\Gamma_{2}}X(x)-i\sqrt{2\pi\Gamma_{1}}Y(x)]} $$
Where $Q,X$ and $Y$ are matrix valued fields.

The idea is to integrate out $X$ and $Y$ from the above expression using saddle point of $Q$. Which satisfies the condition $Q = U^{\dagger}\Lambda U$ for some Lie group $U$. In addition to that the matrix $Q$ satisfy the following constraints
$$Tr(Q)=0\quad, Q^2=\mathbf{1}\quad Q^{\dagger} = Q$$
Expansion around the saddle point $\Lambda$ gives the action in the form bellow

\begin{equation}
S[Q,X,Y]=\int DX DY DQ~e^{iS_{X}[x]}e^{iS_{Y}[y]}e^{\int d^{d}x!Tr~ln(-i\Omega-i(\nabla^{2}/2m+E_{F})+\eta\Lambda+Q(x)-\sqrt{2\pi\Gamma_{2}}X-\sqrt{2\pi\Gamma_{1}}Y)}
\end{equation}
Which is the equation (36) of the paper.
Can anyone please shed some light how to do this type of saddle point approximation to get the last integral.